# Oracle WE8MSWIN1252 characterset in unix based system

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm searching to migrate an ORACLE 11 database based in Windows system and with WE8MSWIN1252 characterset to an ORACLE 12 based in Unix system.

The WE8MSWIN1252 character set is an option in a Unix based system or is a Windows exclusive Character set?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `WE8MSWIN1252` also on Unix systems, at least at [Choosing a Character Set](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch2charset.htm) there is nothing mentioned about that. The only restriction seems to be:

> ASCII-based character sets are supported only on ASCII-based
>   platforms. Similarly, you can use an EBCDIC-based character set only
>   on EBCDIC-based platforms.

However, you should consider to migrate to Unicode AL32UTF8, see [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011)

Answer (score 0):

On the oracle server, you can set any encoding that the DBMS supports. In my practice, I used the `cl8mswin1251` character set on the UNIX Solaris, Linux server.
If the character set database and the client is the same, then no conversion is required.